# How to set default value using alter table statement in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I want to set default value constraint

I have written the following sql

```
ALTER TABLE vote
    ADD CONSTRAINT deVote DEFAULT false FOR status
```

But it's giving error: Column names are not permitted

What I am doing wrong. Help

Thanks

Comment: just to confirm you are setting `False` for a Column called `deVote` in table called `Vote`, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If column is a VARCHAR data type*

```
ALTER TABLE vote
ADD CONSTRAINT df_devote_default DEFAULT 'false' FOR [status];
```

*If column is a BIT data type*

```
ALTER TABLE vote
ADD CONSTRAINT df_devote_default DEFAULT 0 FOR [status];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE vote ADD CONSTRAINT deVote  DEFAULT N'false' FOR status;
```

Comment: thanks it's working. can u please explain what is and why u added n'false'?

Comment: @xyz:- If 'false' is working  then it clearly indicates that the column is varchar so you need to provide a varchar value. So when you say 'false' then it is a varchar value and without quotes it is not. Hope that helps!

Comment: Also if this column will only store `True/False` values, you should make it `BIT datatype` you will save a lot of disk space as well as some performance gain too.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE vote
ALTER  deVote  SET DEFAULT 'false' FOR status
```

Comment: Some explanation for anyone else who finds this answer would be useful